# Simulator has black screen and does not load

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

Normally, when I start the iPhone simulator, the chosen simluator appears, I get a black screen and a loading indicator in the screen of the phone.

Today, I started the simulator (not prom a Xcode project or something else, but from the App Simulator, searched with Spotlight) and the only thing there is: a black screen. No loading indicator, nothing. There is nothing happening. The phone just stays black... I did not update Xcode, the simulator, nor am I starting the Simulator from a project, but from the "bare" Simulator App.

What I tried so far to solve the issue:

1. I tried changing the simulator to another device, with the same result. I tried `Erase Content and Settings` but that did not even open the usual menue I see.
2. Open the `Activity Monitor`, search for `sim` and kill all processes
3. Open the terminal, `sudo xcrun simctl erase all` but that goes on and on and on forever and yields no results. Not sure what is happening there.
4. Restart the computer.
5. Try another phone on the simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why this helped, but I opened a random Xcode project and did a `deep cache clean` through `cmd+alt+shif+k` and now it works...